# Retrieve array values inside foreach() loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to output Wordpress' navigation menu items along with their CSS Classes.

I was able to get the menu items, but the classes are more complicated. the css classes come in an array but it's already inside a `foreach()` loop.

```
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

$menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '">';

foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
    $title = $menu_item->title;
    $url = $menu_item->url;
    $classes = $menu_item->classes;

    $menu_list .= '<li>';
    $menu_list .= '<i class=""></i>';
    $menu_list .= '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a>';
    $menu_list .= '</li>';
}

$menu_list .= '</ul>';
```

As you can see, inside the `foreach()` loop I am getting the `$title` and `$url` which are both strings. But then when I try to get the css classes associated with the menu item through `$menu_item->classes` it returns an array and I am not sure how to do this.

Because each menu item has 3 css classses `fa fa-user fa-3x` I can return the values using this

```
$classes[0] . $classes[1] . $classes[2]
```

But suppose I don't want the third class and I leave it out empty, I get a missing offset error.

I also tried doing a foreach within the original foreach

```
$menu_list .= '<li>';
foreach($classes as $class) {
    $menu_list .= '<i class="'. $class .'"></i>';
}
$menu_list .= '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a>';
$menu_list .= '</li>';
```

But this returns 3 separate `<i>` tags for each menu item, which is not what I want. The output looks like this

```
<i class="fa"></i>
<i class="fa-user"></i>
<i class="fa-3x"></i>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a nested Loop in place like so:

```
<?php

    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

    $menu_list  = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '">';

    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
        $title      = $menu_item->title;
        $url        = $menu_item->url;
        $classes    = $menu_item->classes;
        $comboClass = "";

        // USING NESTED LOOP CONSTRUCT
        foreach($classes as $class){
            $comboClass .= $class . " "; // SEPARATE CLASS-NAME WITH A SPACE
        }

        $menu_list .= '<li>';
        $menu_list .= '<i class="' .$comboClass . '"></i>';
        $menu_list .= '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a>';
        $menu_list .= '</li>';
    }

    $menu_list .= '</ul>';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can nest loops...

```
foreach(...) {
   ... html stuff ..
   echo '<div class="';
   foreach($classes as $class) {
     echo $class, ' ';
   }
   echo '">...</div>';
}
```